# Creation of DataFrame with specific conditions on rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following python pandas DataFrame:

| ID | country | money | other | money_add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 832932 | France | 12131 | 19 | 82932 |
| 217#8# |  |  |  |  |
| 1329T2 |  |  |  |  |
| 832932 | France |  | 30 |  |
| 31728# |  |  |  |  |

I would like to make the following modifications for each row:

- If the `ID` column has any '#' value, the row is left unchanged.
- If the `ID` column has no '#' value, and country is NaN, "Other" is added to the country column, and a 0 is added to `other` column.

Finally, only if the `money` column is NaN and the `other` column has value, we assign the values `money` and `money_add` from the following table:

| other_ID | money | money_add |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 4532 | 723823 |
| 50 | 1213 | 238232 |
| 18 | 1813 | 273283 |
| 30 | 1313 | 83293 |
| 0 | 8932 | 3920 |

Example of the resulting table:

| ID | country | money | other | money_add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 832932 | France | 12131 | 19 | 82932 |
| 217#8# |  |  |  |  |
| 1329T2 | Other | 8932 | 0 | 3920 |
| 832932 | France | 1313 | 30 | 83293 |
| 31728# |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set values to both columns if match both conditions by `list`, then filter non `#` rows and update values by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) only matched rows:

```
m1 = df['ID'].str.contains('#')
m2 = df['country'].isna()

df.loc[~m1 & m2, ['country','other']] = ['Other',0]

df1 = df1.set_index(df1['other_ID'])
df = df.set_index(df['other'].mask(m1))
df.update(df1, overwrite=False)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       ID country   money  other  money_add
0  832932  France   12131   19.0    82932.0
1  217#8#     NaN       ;    NaN        NaN
2  1329T2   Other  8932.0    0.0     3920.0
3  832932  France  1313.0   30.0    83293.0
4  31728#     NaN     NaN    NaN        NaN
```

Comment: There is a problem related with duplicate labels: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels with this sequence: ```df.update(df1, overwrite=False)```